# Android get DuplicateFileException Error for Retrofit and Retrofit Adapter

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit

after installing this libraries on project:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

i get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
File1: /Users/mahdi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.0.1/57f850a6b317e5582f1dbaff10a9e7d7e1fcdcfb/rxjava-2.0.1.jar
File2: /Users/mahdi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.1.5/ece7b5d0870e66d8226dab6dcf47a2b12afff061/rxjava-1.1.5.jar
```

I'm not sure whats problem, some documents installed them like with my solution.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.0.1/57f850a6b317e5582f1dbaff10a9e7d7e1fcdcfb/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/io.reactivex/rxjava/rxjava.properties'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem resolved:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
```